# z-index hover border change

Tags: javascript, css, image, css-tables

I'm trying to add a transparent border on hover to the td below the table above. Trying to recreate the effect thats on top. I'm unsure if this is possible with CSS and I might have to intervene with Javascript/jQuery.

Secondly I'm trying to improve the load time from all of the images. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Here is the [example](http://uriahgray.com/ns2/ns2.html)

Comment: Just a tip: Don't use tables for layout & use a CSS Sprite instead of a bunch of images.

Comment: Can I cut up the image and move them around on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the border is transparent then it's not going to show. Nothing will be different visually.

If i understand what you are trying to do, try this:

```
table#table_01 td:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks @brenjt I was trying to select the table below the table above. I realise this is not going to happen with transparent borders. Thanks for your help.